# Java outlook integration

Tags: java, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I have a program that must 'prepare' emails for me. When the email is prepared, it should show in outlook (or an other email client - default user mail client).

I have used the `Desktop.getDesktop().mail` approach, but I'm very limited with the options. (I cannot set the high importance). An other option I've tried is JavaMail. But here the mail will be send instead of opened in the email client. (same for Apache POI).

An other option I've considered is to write a `.msg`/`.eml` file and open it, but this must be done manually (via java I get a 'file not found' error or an error regarding privileges).

Does anyone know other options or other approaches I might have missed / overlooked?

Comment: so, you want to actually send the email, or just open it with the client? and does it matter for you which client will be used to read the email?

Comment: Open / view in the client (Outlook most likely because this is the default mail client).

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of moyosoft's connector to access outlook functionality from java. Please refer to below url's for more details on this.

http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/

http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/getstarted/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I've checked that out already, but it's not freeware. That's why I gave it up

Comment: Ok, what all functions from outlook you require to access from java.

Comment: Basically, only email functionality.
To be able to set the importance of a message is required. (default signature aswel if possible)

Comment: For setting importance of mail to High add following fragment to mail header. message.addheader("X-Priority", 2);

Comment: using... which method?
I've created a .eml file where the priority is set to high, and that works fine. only I cannot display it in the mail client! (unless I open it manually, which is not best-practice.

Comment: Importance Settings for your refernce
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
X-Priority: 2 (High)
[for normal priority, do nothing]
X-Priority: 4 (Low)
X-Priority: 5 (Lowest)